# AWS Circular Dependency error while EC2 depends on elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, elastic-load-balancer

I got circular dependecy error for elb and ec2 ec2 is depends on elb so after elb generate it can redirect the request to ec2 but I can not achieve it.

Can you please help me. Here I am doing one VPC with 2 subnets public and private subnet and ec2 using private subnet and elb is using public subnet of that vpc now when request will come it will go to elb then ec2

Requests--------> ELB-------->EC2

Like below ways

But While validating I got error

```
Circular dependency between resources: [Instance, elb]
```

I am new on the cloud formation so any help will really helpful for me

```

`````
 {
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "A VPC environment in two availability zones with an NAT instance.",
  "Parameters": {
    "envPrefix": {
      "Description": "Environment name prefix.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "Test"
    },
     "InstanceType": {
      "Description": "Type of EC2 instance to launch",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t1.micro"
    },
    "vpcCidr": {
      "Description": "VPC CIDR block.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "10.4.0.0/16",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    },
    "publicSubnet1Cidr": {
      "Description": "Public subnet 1 CIDR block.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "10.4.0.0/24",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x and subnet of VPC."
    },
    "privateSubnet1Cidr": {
      "Description": "Private subnet 1 CIDR block.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "10.4.1.0/24",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x and subnet of VPC."
    },
    "subnet1AZ": {
      "Description": "Subnet 1 availability zone.",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name"
    },
    "subnet2AZ": {
      "Description": "Subnet 2 availability zone.",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name"
    },
    "natInstanceType": {
      "Description": "Amazon EC2 instance type for the NAT instance. This instance will be put on public subnet 1.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t2.small",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "t2.micro",
        "t2.small",
        "t2.medium",
        "t2.large",
        "m3.medium",
        "m3.large",
        "m3.xlarge",
        "m3.2xlarge",
        "m4.large",
        "m4.xlarge",
        "m4.2xlarge",
        "m4.4xlarge",
        "m4.10xlarge"
      ]
    },
    "natSshAccessCidr": {
      "Description": "IP CIDR from where you could SSH into NAT instance",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    },
    "natKeyName": {
      "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to NAT instances.",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription": "Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    }
  },
  "Mappings": {
    "AWSNATAMI": {
      "eu-central-1": {
        "AMI": "ami-46073a5b"
      },
      "sa-east-1": {
        "AMI": "ami-fbfa41e6"
      },
      "ap-northeast-1": {
        "AMI": "ami-03cf3903"
      },
      "eu-west-1": {
        "AMI": "ami-6975eb1e"
      },
      "us-east-1": {
        "AMI": "ami-303b1458"
      },
      "us-west-1": {
        "AMI": "ami-7da94839"
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "AMI": "ami-69ae8259"
      },
      "ap-southeast-2": {
        "AMI": "ami-e7ee9edd"
      },
      "ap-southeast-1": {
        "AMI": "ami-b49dace6"
      }
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "vpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "vpcCidr"
        },
        "InstanceTenancy": "default",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "VPC"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "publicSubnet1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc",
        "attachGateway"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "publicSubnet1Cidr"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Ref": "subnet1AZ"
        },
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "vpc"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "Subnet-Public-1"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "privateSubnet1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc",
        "attachGateway"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "privateSubnet1Cidr"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Ref": "subnet1AZ"
        },
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "vpc"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "Subnet-Private-1"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "inetGateway": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "InternetGateway"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "attachGateway": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc",
        "inetGateway"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "vpc"
        },
        "InternetGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "inetGateway"
        }
      }
    },
    "rtbPublic": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc",
        "attachGateway"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "vpc"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "RTB-Public"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "routePublic": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "DependsOn": "attachGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "rtbPublic"
        },
        "GatewayId": {
          "Ref": "inetGateway"
        }
      }
    },
    "subnetRouteTableAssociationPublic1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "DependsOn": [
        "rtbPublic",
        "publicSubnet1"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "rtbPublic"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "publicSubnet1"
        }
      }
    },
    "rtbPrivate": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "vpc"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "RTB-Private"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "subnetRouteTableAssociationPrivate1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "DependsOn": [
        "rtbPublic",
        "privateSubnet1"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "rtbPrivate"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "privateSubnet1"
        }
      }
    },
    "natEc2Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc",
        "attachGateway",
        "privateSubnet1",
        "sgNAT"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "DisableApiTermination": "false",
        "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior": "stop",
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "natInstanceType"
        },
        "ImageId": {
          "Fn::FindInMap": [
            "AWSNATAMI",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            "AMI"
          ]
        },
        "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "natKeyName"
        },
        "Monitoring": "false",
        "SourceDestCheck": "false",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "NAT"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "NetworkInterfaces": [
          {
            "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
            "Description": "Primary network interface",
            "DeviceIndex": 0,
            "SubnetId": {
              "Ref": "publicSubnet1"
            },
            "GroupSet": [
              {
                "Ref": "sgNAT"
              }
            ],
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "sgNAT": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "DependsOn": [
        "vpc",
        "attachGateway"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Security group for NAT instances",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "vpc"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "0",
            "ToPort": "1024",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "privateSubnet1Cidr"
            }
          },
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "22",
            "ToPort": "22",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "natSshAccessCidr"
            }
          }
        ],
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }
        ],
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  {
                    "Ref": "envPrefix"
                  },
                  "SG-NAT"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "routePrivate": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "rtbPrivate"
        },
        "InstanceId": {
          "Ref": "natEc2Instance"
        }
      }
    },


"elb" : {
   "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
   "Properties": {
       "HealthCheck" : {
            "Target" : "HTTP:80/",
            "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
            "UnhealthyThreshold" : "5",
            "Interval" : "30",
            "Timeout" : "5"
        },
      "LoadBalancerName" : "elbec2",
       "Listeners" : [ {
            "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
            "InstancePort" : "80",
            "Protocol" : "HTTP"
        } ],
       "Instances" : [
            { "Ref" : "Instance" }
        ],
      "Scheme" : "internal",
      "SecurityGroups" : [{"Ref": "sgNAT" }],
      "Subnets" : [ {"Ref": "publicSubnet1"}]
   }
},



    "Instance":{
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "DependsOn": "elb",
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "configSets": {
            "InstallAndRun": [
              "Install"
            ]
          },
          "Install": {
            "packages": {
              "yum": {
                "httpd": []
              }
            },
            "files": {
              "/var/www/html/index.html": {
                "source": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2back/index.html",
                "mode": "000600",
                "owner": "apache",
                "group": "apache"
              },
              "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "[main]\n",
                      "stack=",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                      },
                      "\n",
                      "region=",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "mode": "000400",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root"
              },
              "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                      "triggers=post.update\n",
                      "path=Resources.Instance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                      "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                      "         --stack ",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      },
                      "         --resource Instance ",
                      "         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
                      "         --region ",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n",
                      "runas=root\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "services": {
              "sysvinit": {
                "httpd": {
                  "enabled": "true",
                  "ensureRunning": "true"
                },
                "cfn-hup": {
                  "enabled": "true",
                  "ensureRunning": "true",
                  "files": [
                    "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf",
                    "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": {
          "Fn::FindInMap": [
            "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            {
              "Fn::FindInMap": [
                "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                {
                  "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "Arch"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "InstanceType"
        },
        "NetworkInterfaces": [
          {
            "DeviceIndex": "0",
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
            "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
            "SubnetId": {
              "Ref": "privateSubnet1"
            },
            "GroupSet": [
              {
                "Ref": "sgNAT"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                "         --stack ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                },
                "         --resource Instance ",
                "         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
                "         --region ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "\n",
                "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                "         --stack ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                },
                "         --resource Instance ",
                "         --region ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "\n"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
````
`````

Comment: Can you try taking out `"DependsOn": "elb",`? CloudFormation will do the dependency management itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFormation has the capability to manage resource dependencies. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) CloudFormation documentation on DependsOn attribute that describes the best practices and gives more details.

In your template, remove the `"DependsOn": "elb"` line and give it a try.